# How long should we wait to check for available data after accepting a connection?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, .net-micro-framework

## Situation

We're using the following code to accept incoming HTTP requests.

```
var localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Port);

var serverSocket = new Socket(
    AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
    SocketType.Stream,
    ProtocolType.Tcp);

serverSocket.Bind(localEndPoint);
serverSocket.Listen(backlog: 25);

while (true)
{
    using (var clientSocket = serverSocket.Accept())
    {
        if (clientSocket.Available > 0)
        {
            var builder = new StringBuilder();

            while (clientSocket.Available > 0)
            {
                var currentBytes = new byte[clientSocket.Available];
                var bytesReceived = clientSocket.Receive(currentBytes);

                var currentBytesString = 
                    new string(Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(currentBytes));

                builder.Append(currentBytesString);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Problem

Sometimes `clientSocket.Available` is zero even though the connection has data. The solution we implemented is to wait after accepting the connection before we check whether data is available. We do it like this:

```
var start = DateTime.Now;
var duration = new TimeSpan(0);
while (clientSocket.Available <= 0 || duration.Milliseconds < 1000)
{
    duration = DateTime.Now - start;
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

## Question

After accepting a connection, how long we we need to wait before the connection's data will be available in the socket?

## Working Solution

Thank you to szym for the inspiration for this approach. It is working for now.

```
while (true)
{
    using (var clientSocket = serverSocket.Accept())
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        do
        {
            var currentBytes = new byte[50];
            var bytesReceived = clientSocket.Receive(currentBytes);

            var currentBytesString = 
                new string(Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(currentBytes));

            builder.Append(currentBytesString);
        }
        while (clientSocket.Available > 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just call Read and let it block till data is available?

Comment: I don't know. What is `Available` for in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you might need to wait a while (think crappy networks with huge round-trip times), the default timeout on some platforms is 20 seconds!

However, the approach of checking `Available` in a sleepy-loop is **polling** and is a waste of CPU. You should either block on [`Receive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receive.aspx) which will just wait for data to arrive (perhaps spawn a thread if you need to handle multiple connections), or use a non-blocking approach.

To quote the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.available(v=vs.100).aspx) (emphasis mine):

> If you are using a **non-blocking** Socket, Available is a good way to
>   determine whether data is queued for reading, before calling Receive.
>   The available data is the total amount of data queued in the network
>   buffer for reading. If no data is queued in the network buffer,
>   Available returns 0.

Comment: Where is this `Read` method about which you speak?

Comment: The docs do not list such a method. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Sorry, updated with `Receive` which is the name in .NET sockets.

Comment: The problem with that approach, is that we still need to keep receiving and checking if there are bytes available (see the edit to my question.) Perhaps I can change this to a `do-while` loop and call `Read` first.

Comment: It seems that you can't figure out when to stop `Receive`ing. This is a problem with your network protocol. There's basically two protocol designs: (1) either special byte sequence delimits the end of a message (e.g., \r\n\r\n in HTTP 1.X) or (2) a fixed-size header specifies the structure of the message (e.g., packet length in IP).  What is the network protocol you are trying to implement?

Comment: We're implementing HTTP. So, I suppose we can check of `\r\n\r\n` and then stop, eh?

Comment: Do you mean that HTTP 1.X delimits the end of the headers with \r\n\r\n or that it delimits the end of the message with that? It looks to me that the \r\n\r\n delimits the headers, and then the request body follows.